# Questions migration

Tags: support, migration

Hello,

Could you tell me why sudenly my questions are redirected to the other stackxxx websites since today ?
I'm using the main one (this one) for monthes and know great people here.
It's confusing...

Comment: Post this on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/. This has to do with the site itself, not programming. Your questions get migrated because this site is for programming only. Others are for other topics.

Comment: @AShelly : ok, thank you, I see. But what about the subtitle of the stackoverflow site "Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers". What kind of tag may I put to be understood as an enthusiast programmers... ? That's confusing...

Comment: @Blender : Hmmm... Yes, of course... I ask because I've posted many questions about iPhone programming and they had never been migrated. For example this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984085/games-programming-literature, ar many older ones. And the last one I asked was migrated. I wonder why.

Comment: It's implied by what you ask/post. Tags relate to the content of the question, not your experience. This site is for asking questions about subjects falling under the category of Programming. You're over-thinking it ;)

Comment: @Blender : Ok, thank you, I understand. Can you post your comment as an answer to let me able to accept it and let other people see it as an answered question if they wonder ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not about who you know.  Or where you personally are most comfortable posting your question, it's about the topic of your question fitting within the bounds of the guidelines posted in the sites' FAQ.

Without seeing the specific question you're referring to, I can only imagine that the question was moved because the question fit within the guidelines of one of the other sites.

For example, you originally asked this question on Stack Overflow, but it's not a question about programming, it's a question about Stack Overflow itself, which belongs here.

If we just let everyone just randomly ask whatever question they want anywhere, there would be no point in having sites related to a specific topic, nor would the community be as strong.